# Json Array - retrieve first record in C#

Tags: c#, json, dynamic

I am obtaining a JSON array in a dynamic object.
How can I obtain the first item( equivalent of First for List collection)?
How can I check if Json array is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's *all* you want to do with it, and if the underlying object implements `IEnumerable`, you could use:

```
foreach (dynamic item in array)
{
    // Use it here
    break;
}
```

Or use `First` explicitly:

```
dynamic first = Enumerable.First(array);
```